# How to iterate over an array of object then remove each element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

`someArray = [{name:"Ibrahim", cid:322}, {name:"Ismail", cid:423}];`

As you can see above, this is simple task to do but I haven't found solid way to iterate over this array, perform some action, and later result as below

`someArray = [];`

So far this is what i have come trough

```
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i].action()
    someArray.splice(0,1);
}
```

it just don't work as I expected. Appreciate somebody can provide me the way. Thanks

Comment: I did. But only some can get it removed. Other remain in array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you're incrementing `i`, but modifying the array.

The simple way is just clear out the array at the end:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i].action();
}
someArray.splice(0,someArray.length);
```

but if you *have* to update the array on each pass

```
while (someArray.length) {
    someArray[0].action();
    someArray.splice(0,1);
}
```

or if it's okay to *replace* the array rather than emptying it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i].action()
}
someArray = [];
```

Note that in that last case, if any *other* variable or property is pointing to the old array, it won't get cleaned out. But if `someArray` is the only reference to it, then you could just assign a blank array to it.

Comment: Or iterate in reverse, `for (var i=someArray.length; i--;)`, but just resetting the array at the end seems easier, +1.

Comment: prefer solution #2. Thanks @Tjcrowder

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do

```
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i].action();
}

someArray = [];
```

Comment: So this is the only way. I guess.

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul No, look at TJ's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide the length first, and not count it on each iteration (it is also good for performance)

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hW4Mm/22/

The magic is in this line:
`var len = someArray.length;`

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
while (someArray.length) {
    someArray[0].action();
    someArray.splice(0,1);
}
```

Or:

```
while (someArray.length) {
    someArray.shift().action();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done really simply, by looping over the array, then making it a blank array.
Hope this was helpful!

```
someArray.forEach(function (person) { // Use Array#forEach to itterate
    person.action(); // Call action on person (person = someArray[i] in your example)
});

someArray = []; // Now make someArray = to a blank array
```

Answer (score 0):

wutt??

you want to modify the collection while iterating? you need to put additional logic after removing the item

you have 2 items, ibrahim and ismail

```
when entering the first loop (i = 0, length = 2, 0 < 2 => iterate)
 ibrahim action is called
 and then the ibrahim is removed
when entering the second loop (i = 1, length = 1, 1 < 1 => quit loop)
```